# letter in quotes appearing just after body tag

Tags: javascript, html, magento, dom

We've just launched our new Magento site and the letter 'c' is appearing in quotes immediately after the  tag.  It's not showing up before on my local machine or on our QA site, I've checked the template files and it is not there either.  I'm almost certain it can not be a code issue as we have the same code running locally and on our QA site under version control with GIT.

We've cleared the cache and I've tried checking to see if JavaScript was inserting it with the chrome dev tools but could find nothing.

Strangely, the 'c' is not in the view source document but I can see it with the chrome inspector.

[image]

I also don't think it can be coming from Magento CMS Pages/Blocks as it loading immediately after the  tag.

Comment: If it's not in the page source, then it's definitely added by JS. Is there something else that should be there instead? I'm thinking that it might be an array replaced by a string (`var[0]`) so you get the first character of whatever it is.

Comment: thanks @Shomz any idea how I could debug to identify the script causing this?  I tried setting the chrome inspector to break on subtree modifications of the body tag but it only breaks in jQuery

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, nothing simple/easy comes to my mind, but a "brute force" search for anything that modifies the DOM (innerHTML, textContent, etc.). Or, if you have a fair number of scripts loading, try disabling them one by one so you can narrow down which one does the problem come from.

Comment: do you have a sample url we can look at?

Comment: @Shomz, I disabled javascript in chrome and the c still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the link.  after reviewing the page source, you have an extra c character in the header area:

```
    <!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
c<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate([]);
        //]]></script>
```

Notice that c before the script tag?

Answer (score 1):

Just in support to Benny Lin's very helpful answer.

What was happening was we had our Google Analytics code loading from a template file which contained the stray letter 'c'.  We could see this on our local machines as this templates was disabled in the Magento admin settings, but not on production.

This issue seems to demonstrate that when a stray letter appears within the `<body>` tags on your dev tools inspector and not the view source page it may be because it is in the `<head>` section.  The browser seems to push all poorly formatted html from the `<head>` section into the `<body>` section when rendering.

For example if you open the below html in the chrome browser you will see what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
c<title>Title of the document in head</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var test = "test";
</script>
</head>

<body>
The body of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Also while we were searching for the stray letter, we were ably to remove it with the below JavaScript that targets the offending XML node in the DOM with an XPath expression and removes that node only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function _x(STR_XPATH) {
      var xresult = document.evaluate(STR_XPATH, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
      var xnodes = [];
      var xres;
      while (xres = xresult.iterateNext()) {
          xnodes.push(xres);
      }    
      return xnodes;
  }
  jQuery(_x('//html/body/text()[contains(.,"c")]')).remove();  
</script>
```